# Drag and drop not working properly with native methods

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi I am unsure about the app behaviour whether it's specific to EXT JS app or some other app but protractor native method was not working properly with following code

`browser.actions().mouseDown(source)..mouseMove(destination).mouseUp().perform();`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and tried to use a lot of js combinations but nothing worked at last following code worked like charm

```
// Dragging one element to another.
        await browser.actions().mouseDown(source).perform();
        await browser.sleep(PageHelper.timeout.xs);
        await browser.actions()
            .mouseMove(destination, { x: 0, y: -25 })
            .mouseMove(destination, { x: 0, y: -15 })
            .mouseMove(destination, { x: 0, y: -5 }).perform();
        await browser.sleep(PageHelper.timeout.xs);
        await browser.actions().mouseUp().perform();
        await browser.sleep(PageHelper.timeout.xs);
```

Possible reason of it's working - It let the container get ready when moved the drag over that container